# Should I report issues on iPad?

Tags: discussion, design, ipad, bug-reports

I was using my iPad recently, and realised how weird the formatting was on the SE sites, like really screwed up - profile page, question page, review queues etc. Should I report the issue? Or do I not due to it being a screen size issue?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need may be of interest and https://browsers.stackoverflow.design is also of interest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Many people don't have access to a laptop/desktop, so issues only visible on tablets and phones should be reported as well. Do note that not all pages are [responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/responsive-design) yet, for example https://stackexchange.com/. Having to scroll to see everything is (usually) not a bug.

Do note that the only [officially supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/295232) browser on iPad/iPhone is Safari, and you have to run iOS 15.2 or higher. But the design issues you mentioned aren't usually that browser-specific.

Comment: How do I report the issues though? There are so many issues on the iPad when it comes to design, so do I report them all at once? Or do I just mention briefly some stuff, as nearly everything is screwed up

Comment: IMHO: put all issues with a single page or a group of related pages in one bug report.

Comment: I will try my best, thanks for helping me out in this! :)

Comment: Thanks in advance for your contributions! Do note that it may take months or years for them to be fixed.