# Multiple issues with the site on Safari on iPad

Tags: bug, design, ipad, safari

After asking a question on iPad bug design reports [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380469/should-i-report-issues-on-ipad), I thought I might ask this question to help fix issues with Safari on iPad. This issue has been prevalent for quite a while now, so hopefully this can be fixed in the future. I will also point out some serious issues with the design.

#### Footer:

[image]

There are no spaces between items in the footer - this makes it difficult to work out which links are which.

#### Reputation page on summary page:

[image]

There are no spaces between the bars in the reputation graph on the summary page. This is solved for Firefox though.

#### Question page:

[image]

The views, user name, score, etc. are all so close to each other, making it near illegible.

Other bugs can be found on [ipad](/questions/tagged/ipad) and [safari](/questions/tagged/safari).

Comment: The 2nd screenshot with missing spaces between daily reputation graphs [was reported in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372608/665544) and solved for Firefox. The 1st screenshot is surprising and likely an unresolved issue from [Reducing the weight of our footer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372007/665544). The 3rd screenshot seems like a result of [New post summary designs on site home pages...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081). So 3 unresolved bugs on ipad+Safari from the last 3 major design changes.

Comment: The graph wierdness is not just be safari - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng3VY.jpg noticed this on my phone running android 12 / chrome 103. Not sure of the screen resolution since my phone does this dynamic resolution thing

Comment: Also, version of OS and browser would be handy!

Comment: Voting to close as it is unclear if these versions of the browser are actually supported.

Comment: Based on the pattern, it looks like the browser you're using does not support flexbox (at least not fully). Confirming the version would be good.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek the issue in your screenshot is different and [was diagnosed by Robert Longson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372802) as the impossibility of evenly dividing fixed length of bars per total graph length and likely the browser [not revealing its resolution to the site to avoid fingerprinting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page?page=8&tab=scoredesc#comment1244990_372802). So they are different issues and the issue in the above question was resolved for the other browsers.

Comment: @bad_coder Unless the browser is intentionally degrading the rendered page to prevent tertiary methods of determining the viewport width, then it has nothing to do with fingerprinting. Browsers *usually* don't do that. Browsers *usually* display things correctly and just report wrong, or no, information to JavaScript. The way SE now does that reputation graph relies *entirely* on *the browser* choosing equal bar widths and equally applying the specified gap (specified only once by SE for all of the bars). So, any inconsistency in the bar width or the inter-bar gap is *entirely* in the browser.